Dual monitors won't connect
I recently bought 2 LG monitors and am HP Tower. When I connected the computers it would not read/detect the second monitor. I bought a VGA/HDMI cable so that one monitor is connected to the tower and the other monitor is connected to the tower via HDMI cable. Both monitors are connected together via an HDMI cable. Idk what I am doing wrong or why they won't connect and no one seems to know what is wrong...HELP!!

Disable then reenable something in device manager.
something to do with video display adapter? Monitor?
